# Why does running the example flink app throw this error?

Tags: java, linux, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I'm trying to run the demo app described in https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.10/dev/projectsetup/java_api_quickstart.html.

I generated the project with the given script:

```
curl https://flink.apache.org/q/quickstart.sh | bash -s 1.10.0
```

and built with:

```
mvn clean package
```

But when I try running with:

```
java -jar targets/java -jar quickstart-0.1.jar
```

I get the following errors:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/flink/streaming/api/environment/StreamExecutionEnvironment
        at org.myorg.quickstart.StreamingJob.main(StreamingJob.java:39)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.flink.streaming.api.environment.StreamExecutionEnvironment
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:419)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:352)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:352)
        ... 1 more
```

I have flink in another folder, and have ran bin/start_cluster.sh. I have also been able to run the prepackaged flink applications (in /bin) without issues.

Answer (score 2):

Per default, the `pom.xml` generated by the quickstarts script will not include Flink's dependencies which are required to run the jar directly via `java -jar ...`. In order to run the jar this way, you would need to build an uber-jar which includes all required Flink dependencies. You can do this via activating the profile `add-dependencies-for-IDEA`:

```
mvn clean package -Padd-dependencies-for-IDEA
```

or by changing the scope of the Flink dependencies from `provided` to `compile`.

The reason why Flink's dependencies are not included by default is because when you submit a job to a Flink cluster, then this cluster already contains these dependencies. Therefore, one can keep the size of the generated user jar small by setting the dependencies to provided in the `pom.xml`, which is equivalent to not including them in the jar.